# Azure App Service Plan is Of Linux kind but showing Operating System as Windows

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-linux

I am preparing an infrastructure for one of my angular application on Azure through ARM template, i want to host application on Linux based operating system, thus configured "App service plan" - Kind : "Linux",
When i executed ps script, App Service plan got created but showing Operating system still as Windows.
and showing Plan as Linux App
Could you please enlighten me if this is obvious behavior or am I still missing anything to correctly configure Linux as base operating system for hosting my angular based application.

PS: the LinuxFxVersion are configured to NODE|14lts

[image: Below screenshot for newly created app plan]

Comment: May you please share your ARM template?

Comment: Thank you Andriy for the response, I have figured out what was going wrong, it was happening as i did not configured linuxfx version for all the web app, apparently if App Service Plan is to be hosted on linux, all the dependent apps should correctly configure their respective - Current_Stack  & LinuxFx version

Answer (score 8):

There is a better way to get this solved. In the `properties` section, there is a `reserved` option: set that to `true`. Attaching reference Bicep template; the same can be done in ARM templates.

```
resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2018-02-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  kind: 'linux'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'S1'
    tier: 'Standard'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently linuxFxVersion & Current_Stack is necessary to configure for every site that is to be created under App Service Plan, In my case I was hosting Web App Bot & Angular application with given ARM template where configuration about Fx Version and stack was missing
"

```
siteConfig": {
          "linuxFxVersion": "[parameters('linuxFxVersion')]"
        },
```

And

```
 "netFrameworkVersion": "",
          "metadata": [
            {
              "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
              "value": "dotnetcore"
            }
```

Configured in respective site config areas